# Dynamically creating TextViews in android apps

Tags: android, google-maps, textview

I'm experimenting creating android apps using maps, and I'm hoping to create a textView which will appear when the user clicks on a Marker. The only criteria is that the view must be scrollable (some of the text might be quite long), and easily disposable by the user - either by swiping or some other method.

I've tried the following:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText(marker.getTag().toString());
 }
```

I didn't expect something so simple to work and it didn't. Further research indicates that I may need to place a TextView in my layout xml file, but I am reluctant to do this as my configuration is more or less set.

FWIW, this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Excursions" />
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".05"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Excursions"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".85"
    tools:context=".Excursions" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:background="#004D79"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Enter address">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Find">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Just to clarify what I'm after.
When you click on a marker, a TextView should appear that covers the whole screen, displaying the textual data; since I don't know how much text will be displayed, there should be vertical scrollbars. Somehow, there should be a way to dismiss the new textview, so that the app's appearance will be restored to how it was before the marker was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the layout params

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

As well as add the new view to the parent layout

```
parentLayout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Hi,
I did this and it produces data on screen, but not as expected. It shows a TextView appearing at the bottom of the screen, but which creeps up as markers are clicked. What I really wanted was similar to a DialogBox on Visual C++ that will appear over the whole screen and then when dismissed, the view returns to normal, as if the dialog box/text view had never existed.

Comment: Ah, I don't believe that was included in the question initially. I would suggest going with Oktawian's answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should add this TextView to xml with attribute

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

And change this method:

```
@Override public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) { 
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

Comment: Should the TextView be within the LinearLayout tag (that is, the outermost vertical one)?

Comment: That doesn't matter

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try (currently working on another troublesome aspect of map development atm)